# Elastic Search Query with multiple conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am new to elastic search and I need help for below scenario:

I have two fields **tag** and **author**. I want to search the data with condition

> (tag="1" and (author="A" or author="B")) or (tag="2" and (author="A" or author="C")) or tag="3"

Please give a outline of how to frame the Elastic Search query.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_field_names):

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tag:'1' AND author:('A' OR 'B')) OR (tag:'2' AND author:('A' OR 'C'))"
    }
  }
}
```